# How o display the referrals of level 2 and 3 on multi level marketing

Tags: php

I managed to display the referrals of level 1 like this:

```
<?php $reqfilleul = $db->query("SELECT * FROM parrain WHERE '".$cle."' = idParrain ")->fetchAll(); ?>

<h5>Premier niveau</h5>

<?php if (empty($reqfilleul)) { ?>
<p class="alert alert-danger">Vous n'avez pas encore de filleul</p>

<?php }else { ?>

<?php $i=1; ?>
<?php foreach ($reqfilleul as $result): ?>

<div class="row">
  <div class="d-flex key-feature align-items-center p-3 rounded shadow mt-4">
    <div class="flex-1 content ms-3">
      <h4 class="title mb-0">
        <?= $result['prenom']; ?>
          <?= $result['nom']; ?>
      </h4>
      <p class="text-muted mb-0">
        <?= $result['email']; ?>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php }?>
                                                                ?
```

Now i want to display the level 2 and 3

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, please add more code to support your question. You can also check GROUP BY group_name

Comment: This is how i take the godchildren.
now i want a tethod to take the godchildren oh the godchildren

Comment: and the godchildren of the godchildren of the godchildren